# Styling a row of labels and drop down lists with CSS

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, label

What would be the way to style a bunch of label/drop down lists in a row but, where each drop down list has a label right above it.

Currently I have in my HTML:

```
<label for="select1">Label1</label>
<select id="select1">...<select>

<label for="select2">Label2</label>
<select id="select1">...<select>

<label for="select3">Label3</label>
<select id="select3">...<select>
```

By default, they all line up in one row.
If I apply this style

```
label {
display:block;
}
```

I get all of them lined up in one column, for the lack of the better word.

So how would I style them so that a bunch of label/drop down lists in a row but, where each drop down list has a label right above it? No tables of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update: Refined Cross-browser Display**

Not quite sure what your final goal is, but if I interpreted correctly, I think something like [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5sTY/7/) demonstrates is what you are going for, which uses this (requires setting an explicit `width` to work with):

**CSS**

```css
label, select {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}

label {
    position: relative;
    top: -1.2em;
    left: 5px;
}

select {
    margin: 1.5em 0 0 -100px;
}
```

**Update for Multiple Rows**

Set a wrapper element of fixed width [like this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5sTY/9/) to cause the rows to wrap.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap each "list / label" combination within a block element. You can then float that element to have multiple items on the same row:

```
<div class='lst'>
    <label for="select1">Label1</label>
    <select id="select1">...<select>
</div>

<div class='lst'>
    <label for="select2">Label2</label>
    <select id="select1">...<select>
</div>

<div class='lst'>
    <label for="select3">Label3</label>
    <select id="select3">...<select>
</div>​

div.lst {
 float: left;   
 margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

div.lst label {
 display: block;   
}
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5hAm/
​

Comment: I was kind of trying to avoid divItis. might as well stick it in a table then.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to group the `label` and `select` in another tag like a `p`, `div` or a `fieldset` and then make that element `display:inline-block` or `float:left`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the menu at the top of this page (Questions, Tags, Users, ...)  It's put together with an unordered list.

```
<div class="nav mainnavs">
    <ul>
        <li class="youarehere"><a id="nav-questions" href="/questions">Questions</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-tags" href="/tags">Tags</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-users" href="/users">Users</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-badges" href="/badges">Badges</a></li>
        <li><a id="nav-unanswered" href="/unanswered">Unanswered</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You could stick each of your label/dropdown pairs into a list item.

```
<li>
    <label for="select1">Label1</label>
    <br />
    <select id="select1">...<select>
</li>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted, a list is a valid way to group the `label` and `select` together (though I wouldn't use a `br`).

Comment: doesn't work at all. I have put display:inline attributes on the list as i normally would; and it's still styling it as a column. If I remove <br>, then it's just one row of labels and lists....

Answer (score 0):

I ended up sticking these in a table because I have several of these rows and they all have to line up.

Comment: That is unfortunate, considering my solution could work perfectly fine without all the extra mark-up and keep things aligned for multiple rows (see my [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5sTY/9/)). Of course, I don't know if the `width` requirement was an issue for you.

Comment: ended up trying yours, thanks a bunch! I modified the width; otherwise left as as.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I hated to think you went to a table when it was not really needed.